# InAppWebview for Desktop Apps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, windows, desktop, flutter-inappwebview, inappwebview

I'm currently working on a Flutter project that requires me to integrate web views into a desktop application for Windows, macOS, and Linux. After some research, I discovered that the [**flutter_inappwebview**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin provides excellent support for web views on mobile platforms, however I can't seem to find any resources or examples for use on desktop systems.

I discovered the [**flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface), which appears to be a good solution for offering a consistent interface across multiple platforms. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly integrate it for desktop applications.

Could you please refer me in the direction of any materials or examples that show how to use **flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface** for Windows, macOS, and Linux desktop apps?

I would appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are planning on writing your own desktop implementations of `flutter_inappwebview`, you would not use `flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface`. It's an implementation detail of the plugin, to allow for other implementations beyond those created by the author of the original plugin. You can learn more about that structure in the [Flutter documentation about federated plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#federated-plugins).

If you want to use `flutter_inappwebview` on desktop, you would either have to write your own desktop implementations, or find someone who has published their own implementations.